# Rigid Body option not available

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

First time poster so apologies if this is in the wrong place.

I'm trying to enable physics for rigid body (as per loads of online tutorials) on two objects as I need to get them to crash into each other, however on the *Physics* tab of the objects, the *Rigid Body* option just isn't there.

There are lots of other options (Force Field, Collision, Cloth etc.) so feel like I'm in the right place, just not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Am using version 2.62 if this makes a difference.

Many thanks

Comment: v2.62!? holy cow!! try this: select the object, open the Python Console, type in *bpy.ops.rigidbody.object_add()*, and hit enter.

Comment: Haha I know.... constrained by what they'll install for me in work, apparently that's the latest version they have/are willing to download.

Have tried the python script but to no avail -I'll have a play around with the other options and see if I can get a result, thanks for your help

Comment: If you are constrained by administrative rights you can always download and run the zipped setup which doesn't require installation

Comment: Now that is a wonderful idea, I'll download from home onto USB and try it that way - thank you very much